# npm install trying to install from random fork

Tags: node.js, windows, git, npm, babun

I got a node project that work fine at work on mac, but on windows at home it give me a access right error when I try to do npm install.

in my `package.json` I have this

```
"dependencies": {
  "async": "2.1.4"
}
```

and it give me this error

```
npm ERR! Command failed: git -c core.longpaths=true clone C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_git-remotes\git-github-com-jstewmon-async-git-e757f9b4 C:\Users\username\.babun\cygwin\tmp\npm-17984-bd5d3a5c\git-cache-52562eee\c6a89a49b0d525c41545e8afd9a4fe844033cc52
npm ERR! Cloning into 'C:\Users\username\.babun\cygwin\tmp\npm-17984-bd5d3a5c\git-cache-52562eee\c6a89a49b0d525c41545e8afd9a4fe844033cc52'...
npm ERR! fatal: '/cygdrive/c/Users/username/AppData/Roaming/npm-cache/_git-remotes/git-github-com-jstewmon-async-git-e757f9b4/C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_git-remotes\git-github-com-jstewmon-async-git-e757f9b4' does not appear to be a git repository
npm ERR! fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Please make sure you have the correct access rights
npm ERR! and the repository exists.
```

seem to be trying to install from a fork of async.. I don't get it.

`git-github-com-jstewmon-async-git-e757f9b4`
https://github.com/jstewmon/async

I tried `npm clean cache` with no success.

Comment: Try to run `npm install` command with administrative rights

Comment: After `npm clean cache` did you confirm that `C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache` is empty? You might try deleting that folder altogether.

Comment: neither sudo nor deleting the folder worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in [npm issue 7456](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/7456#issuecomment-149685044)

> I can confirm that this command fails "does not appear to be a git repository" when using the current git bundled with Cygwin (2.4.5) 64 bit.
>
> When I separately download and install [the Windows git distribution (2.6.2.windows.1) (now 2017 2.12.0)](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases), and put the `GIT_HOME` in front of the `CYGWIN_HOME` in the `PATH`, the `npm install` (including the `git clone`) succeeds.
> I installed with the mintty option so that git works properly with docker also.

If you don't want to install Git on Windows, you can instead follow:
"[**npm_on_cygwin**](https://github.com/emigenix/npm_on_cygwin)"
It involved a [patched `git.js`](https://github.com/emigenix/npm_on_cygwin/blob/master/patched_git.js), which will properly managed [Windows path](https://github.com/emigenix/npm_on_cygwin/blob/7ed8e7da8dedad4925491638af37012d90a2b8ad/patched_git.js#L25-L28), instead of blindly concatenate it as in `/cygdrive/c/.../C:\Users\...`.

The [OP Devilwarriors](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1775440/devilwarriors) mentions [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42685962/npm-install-trying-to-install-from-random-fork/42687700?noredirect=1#comment72537273_42687700) the npm [issue 12821](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/12821), a similar problem of double Git installed:

> **[babun](http://babun.github.io/)**'s sandboxed git can't download git repos when used through npm.
> To solve this, you can uninstall babun's git with pact remove git and use the Git for Windows that you already have installed.

Comment: it was this -> https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/12821

but thanks anyway, this lead me to find that other thing.

Comment: @Devilwarriors Great! I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.

Comment: The patched git.js didn't work for me, I had to make my own mods. https://gist.github.com/mathieucarbou/fd5c619816b5efc0d2a8#gistcomment-2142155

Comment: @GenePavlovsky Interesting. Well done. I use WSL these days, so I don't have much interaction with Cygwin.